# Minify not caching according to pagespeed insights

Tags: cache

I started using https://code.google.com/p/minify/ on my site to decrease the amount of http requests. But google's PageSpeed insights tool is telling me that the new reference link isn't being cached. A example of one of the new links that Minify created is this one:

`<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/min/f=css/responsee.css,css/components.css,css/animate.css,owl-carousel/owl.theme.css,owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css" />`

My htaccess file has caching setup just fine and before I combined the .css files everything was being cached according to Pagespeed. Is this a bug or do I have to add a new line to my htaccess file?

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>

    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault                                      "access plus 1 month"

   CSS
    ExpiresByType text/css                              "access plus 1 year"

  # Data interchange
    ExpiresByType application/atom+xml                  "access plus 1 hour"
    ExpiresByType application/rdf+xml                   "access plus 1 hour"
    ExpiresByType application/rss+xml                   "access plus 1 hour"

    ExpiresByType application/json                      "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/ld+json                   "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/schema+json               "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.geo+json              "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/xml                       "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/xml                              "access plus 0 seconds"

  # Favicon (cannot be renamed!) and cursor images
    ExpiresByType image/vnd.microsoft.icon              "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon                          "access plus 1 year"

  # HTML
    ExpiresByType text/html                             "access plus 0 seconds"

  # JavaScript
    ExpiresByType application/javascript                "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript              "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript                       "access plus 1 year"

  # Manifest files
    ExpiresByType application/manifest+json             "access plus 1 year"

    ExpiresByType application/x-web-app-manifest+json   "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest                   "access plus 0 seconds"

  # Media files
    ExpiresByType audio/ogg                             "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/bmp                             "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/gif                             "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg                            "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/png                             "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml                         "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/webp                            "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType video/mp4                             "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType video/ogg                             "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType video/webm                            "access plus 1 week"

  # Web fonts

    # Embedded OpenType (EOT)
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject         "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/eot                              "access plus 1 month"

    # OpenType
    ExpiresByType font/opentype                         "access plus 1 month"

    # TrueType
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf                "access plus 1 month"

    # Web Open Font Format (WOFF) 1.0
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff                 "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff               "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/woff                             "access plus 1 month"

    # Web Open Font Format (WOFF) 2.0
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff2                "access plus 1 month"

  # Other
    ExpiresByType text/x-cross-domain-policy            "access plus 1 week"

</IfModule>
```

EDIT:

Here is the header:

```
GET /min/f=css/responsee.css,css/components.css,css/animate.css,owl-carousel/owl.theme.css,owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0
Accept: text/css,*/*;q=0.1
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://example.com/
Cookie: PHPSESSID= -removed-; 
sc_is_visitor_unique=rx10296953.1429464775.24A3E18F98904F802719FEC9140DFAFF.30.22.19.17.10.6.3.1.1
Connection: keep-alive
If-Modified-Since: Sun, 19 Apr 2015 15:43:07 GMT
If-None-Match: "pub1429458187;gz"
Cache-Control: max-age=0

HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Date: Sun, 19 Apr 2015 17:34:10 GMT
Server: Apache
Connection: Keep-Alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=99
Etag: "pub1429458187;gz"
Expires: Sun, 19 Apr 2015 18:04:10 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=1800
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
```

Comment: Is this returning a `text/css` Content-Type?

Comment: @w3d the tool automatically generates the line of text to enter into your page. The link I posted is the exact link that the tool generated so I'm guessing it is considered `text/css` type but I could be wrong

Comment: You can see what `Content-Type` header your _server_ is responding with by examining the request/response in the browser. This header works with the `ExpiresByType` directive you have in .htaccess. In fact you should be examining the HTTP response headers to see why this resource is not being cached.

Comment: @w3d I edited my orginal post and added the header

Comment: As you can see from the response headers: "304 Not Modified" - this resource _is_ being cached by the browser (which is also probably why there is no `Content-Type` header in the response). The `Cache-Control: max-age=1800` header is telling the browser to cache this response for 30 minutes. I would assume this is being set by the Minify script - which will override mod_expires (which will only set the header if it doesn't already exist).

Comment: I just started with all this so this is really usefull, thanks allot :) If you post this as a answer ill put it as the answer btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see from the response headers (after the edit): "304 Not Modified" - this indicates that the resource *is* being cached by the browser after all (which is also probably why there is no `Content-Type` header in this particular response).

However, this resource is "only" being cached for 30 minutes, which might be why the PageSpeed tool is complaining?

The `Cache-Control: max-age=1800` header is telling the browser to cache this response for 30 minutes (and this matches the `Expires` header when compared with the timestamp of the request).

I would assume the `Cache-Control` headers are being set by the Minify script - which will override mod_expires (which will only set the header if it doesn't already exist).